# how to customize the xsd that axis2 generates

Tags: xsd, apache-axis

I am following the "web service from pojo"[1] bottom-up guide in axis2 documentations, but the wsdl that is generated is not good.
Specifically, the xsd schema that is embedded in the wsdl is not good and I want to customize it. I want to allow cyclic references, in a similar fashion to what jaxb lets you do with XMLID and XMLREFID.

Any ideas?

Thanks

[1] -> http://ws.apache.org/axis2/1_5_1/pojoguide.html

Answer (score 2):

If you use the Netbeans plugin for AXIS2 ([tutorial here](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/gs-axis.html)) you can specify to edit the WSDL, otherwise I can't help, sorry. Maybe you could look at the options available for the ant task?

I do find AXIS2 overly painful compared to other web service frameworks, and the documentation leaves a lot to be desired.

Comment: Thanks. I evaluated axis2, metro and spring-ws, and found metro to be the "nicest". The lack of documentation in axis2, particularly about customizing the xsd (both xsd authoring and xsd generation from java code) is a sore point. metro streamlines that process very well so I ended up choosing metro.